# JavaScript Promises - Value Scope

Tags: javascript, promise

I am attempting to learn promises in JavaScript. One piece is confusing me. That piece is scoping. In an effort to learn about promises, I'm building a small app. The app has a view, some code behind, and a view model. My code behind looks like this:

**codeBehind.js**

```
var viewModel = new (require('./viewModel'))();
exports.viewLoaded = function(args) {
  viewModel.load()
    .then(function() {
      console.log('promise fulfilled.');
      console.log('Title: ' + viewModel.title);
    })
  ;
};
```

As the snippet above shows, a file called viewModel.js is referenced. That file looks like this:

**viewModel.js**

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.title = '[TODO]';
}
ViewModel.prototype = {};

ViewModel.prototype.load = function() {
    console.log('loading...');
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            console.log('processing the promise.');
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.title = 'LOADED';
            resolve();
        }
        catch (ex) {
            reject(ex);
        }
    });     
};
module.exports = ViewModel;
```

When the codeBehind.js viewLoaded function is executed, I see the following in the console window:

```
loading...
processing the promise.
promise fulfilled.
Title: [TODO]
```

I'm confused. I was expecting it to says "Title: LOADED". I feel like there is something I'm misunderstanding regarding promises. What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't it say "Title: LOADED".

Comment: I really do wonder why you're using promises here at all, that `load` function seems to be synchronous. At least try to mock the asynchrony with a timeout :-)

Comment: Btw, that `try`-`catch` is superfluous here. The `Promise` constructor does automatically catch all exceptions that are thrown (synchronously) from the resolver callback, and rejects the promise (like you do manually).